# paper-listbox with strings?

Tags: polymer-1.0, paper-elements

instead of dealing with ints, it seems that i am receiving a string from the database.... that i need to compare against for the DDL i am working with.  That being said, say i pass in: `selected="{{type}}"`

When trying to do something like:

```
 <paper-item value="Internal">Internal</paper-item>
```

it was throwing an error `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'value'`

Here is my current implementation, where type is *String* "External"

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Type" value="{{type}}" no-animations="true">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{type}}">
    <paper-item value="Internal">Internal</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="External">External</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Ideally:  It will want to populate it with the current value by setting that to selected.

I also tried it without paper-item having values.

**Edit**:  I noticed that `paper-dropdown-menu.value` is read only.... so I removed that.  I also noticed that `paper-listbox.selected` is the correct value to assign, but it seems that despite selected="External", it doesnt select the second item at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with a string, if you want it to do as such:

you would have to say: `attr-for-selected="value"` and then you will use selected and it will do comparisons on that against the target attribute.   Here is an updated Markup.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Type" value="{{type}}" no-animations="true">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" 
      attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{type}}">
    <paper-item value="Internal">Internal</paper-item>
    <paper-item value="External">External</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```